# os.popen not working as .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this code as a application(.exe) file it returns a blank output window.

```
import os

r = os.popen('cmd').read()
print(r)
```

[(Output Window)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6OvN.png)

Could someone fix my code or suggest an altenative? 
Edit:
My aim is to run the program as an executable, run the commandin the DOS console and return the output of the command.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[os.popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen):

> Open a pipe to or from command. The return value is an open file
>   object connected to the pipe, which can be read or written depending
>   on whether mode is 'r' (default) or 'w'.

If you just want to call an app:

```
os.popen('app_you_want_call.exe')
```

If you are trying to play interactively with the windows command line, you must do something like:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write("YOUR COMMAND HERE")
```

[More about subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#module-subprocess)

Comment: The code outputs this exception:
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\testing.py", line 3, in <module>
    stdin.write("cmd")
NameError: name 'stdin' is not defined

Comment: Oops, fixed (I've forget `proc.` before `stdin.write`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your patience with my disorganization. Sorry 'bout that